# Django, filter by multiple values

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

So I have these models:

```
Bands(models.Model):
    mgmt = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=200)

Contracts(models.Model):
    band = models.ForeignKey(Bands)
    start_date= models.DateField()

BookedGig(models.Model):
    for  = models.ForeignKey(Bands)
    under= models.ForeignKey(Contracts)
    date = models.DateField()
```

How would I construct something in my views.py file to capture all the BookedGigs for a user? My goal is just to display through a template, the various gigs under the title of the 
contacts/bands.

in views.py I currently have

```
def Home(request):
    user = request.user
    bands = Bands.objects.filter(mgmt=user).order_by('name') 
        #This will give me the bands belonging to a user
    contracts = Contracts.filter(band=bands)
        #But here bands is not one value but a queryset.

    #if I try
    contracts = bands.booked_gig_set.all() 
    I get 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'booked_gig_set'
```

templates: I know this is wrong but this is how I'd like to display the lists.

```
{% for b in bands %}
    Band:{{b.name}}
    {% for c in contracts %}
        Contract Start:{{c.start_date}}
        {% for g in gigs %}
            {{g.dates}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Contracts.objects.filter(band__in=bands)
```

You might want to add a [`prefetch_related` statement](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) there to prefetch the gigs though, otherwise your template loop will hit the DB once per contract.

```
 contracts = Contracts.objects.filter(band__in=bands).prefetch_related()
```

Comment: Just checking, you mean this with the '.objects' in between right?

Comment: I'm new to Django but should you be using a ManyToMany field?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: ManyToMany for which field?

Comment: Thomas, how does this work if bands is a result for a _set.all() query?